Combine dictionaries with common and nonexistent keys without filling the gaps
Here is a list of dictionaries:
dictionaries = [
    {"Key 1": "value1"
     "Key 2": "value2"
     "Key 3": "value3"
    },

    {"Key 1": "value4"
     "Key 3": "value5"
     "Key 4": "value6"
    },

    {"Key 1": "value7"
     "Key 2": "value8"
     "Key 4": "value9"
    }
]

Here are my expected results:
mergedDictionaries = {
    "Key 1": ["value1", "value4", "value7"],
    "Key 2": ["value2", "", "value8"],
    "Key 3": ["value3", "value5", ""],
    "Key 4": ["", "value6", "value9"]
}

I tried using the collections module, but it fills up the gaps using this code below.
dictionary = defaultdict(list)

for key in dictionaries:
    for x, y in key.items():
        dictionary[x].append(y)

The whole point of this is to make an accurate dataframe when combining the dictionaries.
Is there any method to recreate this situation?

You would need to check that a given key is present in each other subdictionary, which you are not doing.

You should collect all appearing keys in a first step and then for each key build the result list by iterating through all input dictionaries and getting the value for the key if present.

A bit tweaking of your algorithm:
result = defaultdict(list)
for i, d in enumerate(dictionaries):
    for k, v in d.items():
        while len(result[k]) < i:
            result[k].append('')
        result[k].append(v)

for k in result:
    while len(result[k]) < len(dictionaries):
        result[k].append('')

result
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Key 1': ['value1', 'value4', 'value7'], 'Key 2': ['value2', '', 'value8'], 'Key 3': ['value3', 'value5', ''], 'Key 4': ['', 'value6', 'value9']})


To create a merged dictionary you can try to check if that key is already in merged dictionary, if yes - append the value, if not - just "".
To get all keys from all dictionaries, just iterate among them and add to set, to have only unique values:
keys = set(key for dict_ in dictionaries for key in dict_)

Now, by .get(key, '') we will get the value of the key, or if not, we will receive the '' string. The setdefault will create a list for the every new key, so we can now append into it the received values.
mergedDictionaries = {}
for key in keys:
    for dict_ in dictionaries:
        mergedDictionaries.setdefault(key, []).append(dict_.get(key, ''))

Hope it works.
Maybe I didn't get about dataframe, but if you wanna get the pandas.DataFrame object, it will me much easier, just using couple of lines:
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionaries)
df = df.fillna('')

